# Consolidating multiple external DB into one single DB

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to design a schema intended to store multiple DB of cars (honda, bmw, opel, etc) in the same DB (consolidated master data).

To keep it simple, let say that each external DB have 3 entities: Model (lookup table), Category (lookup table), Car which refers the two lookup tables.

The problem I have is that Model and Category have completely different data in each external DB (but 99% common attributes). Thus in my consolidated DB how can I keep track of the Model and Category that belongs to each brand ?

Similarly, how can I avoid that a Car of brand Honda refers to Category or Model not belonging to Honda ?

Somehow the brand information should also be stored (lookup table) but how can we avoid to avoid multiple cascade path ?

Thanks !

**UPDATE:**

After reviewing the business requirement, users don't want any transformation / modification of the source data in the consolidated database. They should be kept as they are in the external DB.

Here is an example of data of *Category*:

**HONDA**

- Sport
- Sport Compact
- City Car

NB: "Sport Comptact" has "Sport" for parent

**VW**

- Sport Car
- Sport Compact
- City Car

NB: "Sport Compact" has "Sport Car" for parent

**BMW**

- Super Car
- Hyper Car
- City Car

As example of data of *Model*:

**HONDA**

- Sedan
- Wagon
- Hatchback
- Coupé

**VW**

- SUV
- Sedan - Coupe

**BMW**

- Sport Utility Vehicle (SUV)
- Wagon - Hatchback

[I was thinking of a schema like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ucEQ.png)

All tables are connected to the Brand table, so that the frontend can populate the lookup tables Model and Category independently.

I've brought the Brand ID down to the Car table which allows to ensure that Car referes Model and Category of the same Brand.

BUT, not all SGBDR allows for referencing columns that are not part of PK neither to have multi-columns key.

Things get also complicated if a Car needs to have multiple Category or Model, or if a Car needs to refer to another Car from another Brand (think of Seat which belongs to Volkswagen)

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborate more in which technology are you using, are you talking of relational databases? NoSQL databases?

Comment: All databases are relational since the entities and their properties are well structured. Using SQL Server as the SGBDR.

Comment: Surely Model has a FK to Brand? Is Category a generic list? If so you should create a generic Category table and map from one to the other where appropriate, or create a union of the source tables where there is no equivalent.

Comment: No Brand table exists for now has each external DB is dedicated to and only one brand. Category is generic in each external DB. Unfortunately  I have a few overlapping Category among brands (some reference a parent Category while others not). Should we also have a FK in Category to reference Brand table ? But in that case there is a multiple cascade path from Brand to Car....

Comment: Clearly you need to add a brand table, and create a new structure that allows old data to map onto the combined structure. Its not going to be a direct copy, as you are no doubt going to get primary key collisions between the databases, in addition to differences in structure etc. Nothing we can really do to help, unless we have full schemas for the 3 databases, and an understanding of the data they contain. This is a fairly common scenario, particularly where a consolidated reporting or data warehouse solution is being set up.

Comment: I see you have further updated the question, thanks for that. There is no way around this - if you have multiple source databases, one for each brand, and you don't want to do any other changes, then all the tables will need a Brand column to avoid collisions on their original key. Otherwise you will have to create a Surrogate key for all tables, and use that for all FKs instead. Either of these will introduce complexities, but I dont think there is any way around this.

Comment: Thanks for your help TomC much appreciated.

Comment: I had a previous design where I used a natural key (combination of brand name + id from the external DB) in each core table to avoid linking to a brand table. That is ok for a read-only reporting DB not a transactional one.